# What to use for timeseries: datenum, datetime or timeseries

Tags: matlab, date, datetime, time, time-series

I'm using timeseries all the time and using [datenum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) only.
I heard, that [datetime](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) is better to use or will be better in the future. There also are [Time Series Objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/time-series-objects.html).

What are your recommendations regarding **usability** and **speed**?

Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding usability - `datetime` arrays have a multitude of methods to deal with all sorts of things such as time zones, extraction of parts of the time, conversion to string, plotting, etc. much more conveniently than a `datenum`. Internally, `datetime` uses a pair of `double`s for each point in time, which gives more precision than a `datenum`.

Also useful is the ability to use `datetime` together with [`timetable`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/timetables.html) for time-based data series. `timetable` has many useful methods for retiming and synchronising time-based data.